# Is it possible to place an embedded template within a snippet?

Tags: ee2, templates, snippets

Is it possible to place an embedded template within a snippet?  Reason is I have a client that wants to be able to use the Allow More EE Code plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-more-ee-code to insert certain items into the WYGWAM editor in normal (non-source). Since this plugin does not parse snippet dynamic data, I tried just placing the code [code]{embed="includes/.calendar"}[/code] into the snippet and to my surprise the dynamic data was parsed!  Is it OK to setup a few snippets in this manner to allow the client to insert them were needed or is there a big drawback?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't notice any performance hits, its perfectly acceptable.

Another solution you might try is to use Low Variables instead of embeds. This is possible as of version 2.3 thanks to this parameter:

```
preparse:my_var=""
```

Read more about this method [here](http://leereamsnyder.com/blog/low-variables-230-totally-killed-the-embed-tag).

Comment: can you insert Low Variables into a WYGWAM editor?